# How to show the results of `open :x for <<select statement>>` in query results window in SQL Developer

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to show the results of the following anon block in sql developer's results grid?

```
declare
begin
  select 1 from dual;
end;
/
```

In Toad I remember doing something like

```
declare
begin
  open :x for
    select 1 from dual;
end;
/
```

And then entering cursor on the "binding?" dialog box.

**UPDATE**

The answer is no, you can not do this is SQL Developer as you would in Toad, but there is a "[workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672019/run-sql-code-with-variables-in-oracle-sql-developer-code-window)" that I used instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a script, not a single statement. The data grids are reserved for single, SQL SELECT statements. Put your cursor on the select bit and hit ctrl+ENTER if you want the results in a grid.